# Quiz is not showing questions past question two

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a JavaScript/HTML based quiz in my free time, however I have ran into an issue: It goes up to question 2 then it doesn't show the next question, I have checked the console for any errors but there are none to be seen.

I apologise that it is not the most complex code, I am still learning JS. If anybody could point me to where I went wrong it would be great!

```
var questions = ["What one of these New Zealand birds is dubbed 'Owl Parrot'","Q2","Q3"];
var answers = {
  1:{
     1:"Kea",
     2:"Kakapo",
     3:"Kiwi",
     4:"Takahe",
     c:2
  },
  2:{
    1:"DEBUG",
    2:"DEBUG",
    3:"DEBUG",
    4:"DEBUG",
    c:4
  },
  3:{
    1:"DEBUG2",
    2:"DEBUG2",
    3:"DEBUG2",
    4:"DEBUG2",
    c:1
  }
};

var score = 0;
var question = -1;
function play(){
  question = question + 1;
  askquestion(question);
}
function askquestion(q){
  console.log(q);
  document.getElementById("StartButton").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("Question").innerHTML = questions[q];
  document.getElementById("Answer1").innerHTML = answers[q+1][1];
  document.getElementById("Answer2").innerHTML = answers[q+1][2];
  document.getElementById("Answer3").innerHTML = answers[q+1][3];
  document.getElementById("Answer4").innerHTML = answers[q+1][4];
  
}

function answerquestion(a){
  console.log(a);
    if (answers[question+1]["c"] == a){
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Correct!";

    }else{
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "Incorrect!";

    }
    if (question + 1 < questions.length + 1 ){
      console.log(question+1,questions.length);
      askquestion(question+1);
    }else{
      question = -1;
    }
  }
```

Sorry if this post was formatted wrong, it is my first time on this site.

Comment: Could you please also add your html and css ?

Comment: you never update the value of `question`, you need to set it to `question  = question +1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never update the value of your `question` variable. That keeps your state.
In your `answerquestion` method you can have:

```
...
 if (question < questions.length ){
      question = question+1
      console.log(question,questions.length);
      askquestion(question);
 }
```

Comment: We've all been there, don't worry!